# I made 4 columns with bootstrap but I want some margin between them but the 4 th column is going to the next line how I can solve this problem?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I made 4 columns with bootstrap and I want some margin between this columns ,but when I put some margin (15px) the last column is jumping to the next line.
I tried ml property of bootstrap but the problem still exist.
how I can solve this problem.
my html code is :

```
 <div class="row ">
<div class="home-content3-image1 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 "></div>
<div class="home-content3-image2 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 "></div>
<div class="home-content3-image3 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 "></div>
<div class="home-content3-image4 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 "></div>
```

my url is :http://webdesignleren.com/

Answer (score 0):

Take another div in col and add `class="home-content3- image-1"` to it. So that you can get some space between them.

```
<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="home-content3-image1 w-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="home-content3-image2 w-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="home-content3-image3 w-100"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
    <div class="home-content3-image1 w-100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I clicked on votes ,I don't know if it is upvote is

Comment: Please accept and up vote my answer, if your requirement is done.